Error while using redis server using Docker
I am trying to connect my docker container and redis server but am getting the following error:
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-stack-server
talawa-api-dev-1      | [0]     at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:563:5)
talawa-api-dev-1      | [0]     at __node_internal_ (node:internal/errors:782:10)
talawa-api-dev-1      | [0]     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
talawa-api-dev-1      | [0]     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)

I have already setup redis-server using Windows WLS in Ubuntu distribution.
when i rundocker ps, I can see an active redis-server container running, but am still getting this error.
Here are my .env file and docker-compose.dev.yaml file:
NODE_ENV=development
SERVER_PORT=4000
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_PASSWORD=

version: "3.8"

services:
 mongodb:
   image: mongo:latest
   ports:
     - 27017:27017
   volumes:
     - mongodb-data:/data/db
   networks:
     - talawa-network

 redis-stack-server:
   image: redis/redis-stack-server:latest
   ports:
     - 6379:6379
   volumes:
     - redis-data:/data/redis
   networks:
     - talawa-network

 minio:
   image: minio/minio
   ports:
     - "9000:9000"
     - "9001:9001"
   environment:
     - MINIO_ROOT_USER=${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
     - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
   command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
   volumes:
     - minio-data:/data
   networks:
     - talawa-network

 talawa-api-dev:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
   volumes:
     - .:/usr/src/app
     - /usr/src/app/node_modules
   depends_on:
     - mongodb
     - redis-stack-server
     - minio
   environment:
     - MONGO_DB_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017
     - REDIS_HOST=redis-stack-server
     - REDIS_PORT=6379

 caddy:
   image: caddy/caddy:2.2.1-alpine
   container_name: caddy-service
   restart: unless-stopped
   ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
   volumes:
     - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
     - ./site:/srv
     - caddy_data:/data
     - caddy_config:/config

volumes:
 mongodb-data:
 redis-data:
 caddy_data:
 caddy_config:
 minio-data:

networks:
 talawa-network:
   driver: bridge


I have already setup redis-server using Windows WLS in Ubuntu distribution.
when i rundocker ps, I can see an active redis-server container running, but am still getting this error.

Everything taking to your redis server needs to be on a shared network, in this case:
    networks:
     - talawa-network

